# The heat bath algorithm for $SU(3)$ lattice gauge field

Tags: gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-gauge-theory

I'm studying lattice gauge theory and succeeded in simulating $U(1)$, $SU(2)$ with a heat bath algorithm. However, I have difficulty in applying the algorithm to $SU(3)$. I refer to Gattringer and Lang's lecture note, "Quantum Chromodynamics on the Lattice" and it shows how to update an old variable by applying $SU(2)$ heat bath method to the $SU(2)$ subgroups of $SU(3)$. I also refer to the original paper by Cabibbo, Marinari and Creutz and I can understand $SU(2)$ heat bath.

What confuses me most is that the sub-matrix which corresponds to the sum of plaquettes is not actually an element of $SU(2)$ in $SU(3)$ gauge case but teated as if it were.
I suppose the component of the sub-matrix becomes like that of $SU(2)$ after tracing and getting real part.
I want to know how to get the $SU(2)$ subgroup matrix and update an old link variable after getting the matrix.
A detailed explanation or pseudocode about it will be helpful to me.

Comment: Reading from Gattringer and Lang, they mention after (4.48) that the change in the action when considering an SU(2) block is only influenced by the terms in the sum of the staples corresponding to that SU(2) block (so even though the sum of staples lives in SU(3), you do the SU(2)-heatbath algorithm for the SU(2) sub-block of the sum of staples operator)

Comment: I found in my code the way of extracting the SU(2) block was wrong. Thanks anyway!