# Lattice QCD $SU(3)$ Pseudo Heat Bath Algorithm in Practice

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-gauge-theory

I'm doing a Lattice QCD project and would like to use the pseudo heat bath algorithm for updating links. I've been following [Gattringer and Lang's "Quantum Chromodynamics on the Lattice"](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-01850-3). Reading section 4.3.1, I'm confused about the details of implementing the algorithm. Towards the end of this section, they state that "... $W$ plays the role of $A$...", so I calculate $W$. For the first $SU(2)$ subgroup, I take the upper left $2\times 2$ sub-block of $W$ (let's call it $W_{UL}$) and proceed with the algorithm as described in §4.3.1 to find the upper left $2\times 2$ sub-block of the matrix they call $R$.

In the context of this section of the book, it's clear that $\text{det}(A)$ and, by extension, $a=\sqrt{\text{det}(A)}$ must be real numbers but, when I calculate $\text{det}(W_{UL})$, I find that it's complex! This then stops me from calculating anything meaningful. I don't know what's going wrong - I suspect I may have misunderstood how to generalise the algorithm to $SU(3)$. If someone can detail how it's *supposed* to be applied to $SU(3)$, I would greatly appreciate it.

I even went back to [the original paper by Cabibbo and Marinari](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(82)90696-7) but to no avail. I also found [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/640135/the-heat-bath-algorithm-for-su3-lattice-gauge-field) Physics SE question but the resolution to the OP's problem is not explained (and I currently don't have enough reputation to comment and ask about it).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the paper
"Improved heatbath method for Monte Carlo calculations in lattice gauge theories" which uses the O(4) representation of SU(2)
So for each subgroup, calculate the O(4) rep. according to
$ O(0) = Re(u_{00}) + Re(u_{11})$

$ O(1) = Im(u_{01}) + Im(u_{10})$

$ O(2) = Re(u_{01}) - Re(u_{10})$

$ O(3) = Im(u_{00}) - Im(u_{11})$

and calculate $a = \sqrt{O\cdot O}$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).